# For loop is being skipped

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm running out of ideas here. What I want is very simple, tempArray is an arraylist of five strings that's being generated by the function. The for-each loop is supposed to iterate through twoArray, an arraylist of arrayList, check if the values of the current tempArray are present, and if not, add the current tempArray, but for some reason it is being skipped.

```
/*
* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/

package pal;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

/**
 *
 * @author Weatherman
 */
public class Main {
public static int graphCount = 0;
public static ArrayList<String> testArray = new ArrayList<String>();
//public static
public static void generateCombinations(ArrayList<String> listEdges,ArrayList<String> tempArray, int start, int end,int index,int r,int numberOfNodes, int numberOfC, int numberOfN, int numberOfO)
{

    int[] nodeCounter = new int[numberOfNodes+1];
    int[] nodeCounter2 = new int[numberOfNodes+1];
    int[] nodeCounter3 = new int[numberOfNodes+1];
    ArrayList<String> iteratorArray = new ArrayList<String>(r);
    ArrayList<String> finalArray = new ArrayList<String>(r);
    int notAllNodesBreaker = 0;
    int tooManyConnectionsBreaker = 0;
    int notEnoughCycleEdgesBreaker = 0;
    int notACycleBreaker = 0;
    //ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> oneArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> twoArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

      if(index==r)
      {
          for(int k=0;k<r;k++)
          {
              String[] stringArray = tempArray.get(k).split(" ");
              int temp1 = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[0]);
              int temp2 = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[1]);
              nodeCounter[temp1]++;
              nodeCounter[temp2]++;
          }

          for(int l=1;l<=numberOfNodes;l++)
              {
                  if(nodeCounter[l]==0)
                  {
                      notAllNodesBreaker = 1;
                  }
              }
          for(int l=1;l<=numberOfC;l++)
              {
                if(nodeCounter[l]>4)
                  {
                      tooManyConnectionsBreaker = 1;
                  }
              }
          for(int l=numberOfC+1;l<=numberOfC+numberOfN;l++)
              {
                if(nodeCounter[l]>3)
                  {
                      tooManyConnectionsBreaker = 1;
                  }
              }
          for(int l=numberOfC+numberOfN+1;l<=numberOfNodes;l++)
              {
                if(nodeCounter[l]>2)
                  {
                      tooManyConnectionsBreaker = 1;
                  }
              }

          //eliminace duplicitnich hran
          outer: for(String element : tempArray)
          {
                for(String inElement : iteratorArray)
                {
                    if(element.equals(inElement))
                    {
                        continue outer;
                    }
                }
                iteratorArray.add(element);
          }
          if(iteratorArray.size()<3)
          {
              notEnoughCycleEdgesBreaker = 1;
          }

          //hledani single elementu
          for(String inElement : iteratorArray)
          {
              String[] stringArray = inElement.split(" ");
              int temp1 = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[0]);
              int temp2 = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[1]);
              nodeCounter2[temp1]++;
              nodeCounter2[temp2]++;
          }


          //vyrazeni single elementu

                for(String inElement : iteratorArray)
                {
                 String[] stringArray = inElement.split(" ");
                 int temp1 = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[0]);
                 int temp2 = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[1]);

                 if(nodeCounter2[temp1] == 1 || nodeCounter2[temp2] == 1)
                     {

                     }
                  else
                     {
                     finalArray.add(inElement);
                     }
                }



          if(finalArray.size()<3)
              {
                  notEnoughCycleEdgesBreaker = 1;
              }

          //hledani cyklu
          for(String inElement : finalArray)
          {
              String[] stringArray = inElement.split(" ");
              int temp1 = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[0]);
              int temp2 = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[1]);
              nodeCounter3[temp1]++;
              nodeCounter3[temp2]++;
          }

          for(int l=1;l<=numberOfNodes;l++)
              {
                  if(nodeCounter3[l]==2||nodeCounter3[l]==0)
                  {

                  }
                  else
                  {
                     notACycleBreaker = 1;
                   }
              }

          for(int j=0;j<r;j++)
          {

              if(tempArray.equals(testArray))
              {
                  return;
              }
              else if(notAllNodesBreaker == 1 || tooManyConnectionsBreaker == 1 || notEnoughCycleEdgesBreaker == 1 || notACycleBreaker == 1)
              {
                  return;
              }
              else
              {                      
              //System.out.print(tempArray.get(j));
              //System.out.print(";");                    
              }
          }
          //oneArray.add(tempArray);
          //outer: for(ArrayList<String> element : oneArray)
                 //  {
```

This is the for loop that's giving me trouble:

```
           for(ArrayList<String> element : twoArray)
                {
                   if(tempArray.equals(element))
                        {
                            //continue outer;

                        }
                    else
                        {
                        twoArray.add(tempArray);
                        }
                  }
```

And here's the rest of the code:

```
          for(int x=0;x<twoArray.size();x++)
          {
              for(int y=0;y<tempArray.size();y++)
              {
                  System.out.print(twoArray.get(x).get(y));
                  System.out.print(";");
              }
          }
          System.out.print("\n");
          testArray = new ArrayList<String>(tempArray);
          return;

      }

     for(int i=start; i<=end && end-i+1 >=r-index; i++)
     {
          tempArray.set(index, listEdges.get(i));
          generateCombinations(listEdges, tempArray, i+1, end, index+1, r, numberOfNodes,numberOfC,numberOfN,numberOfO);
     }


  }

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
   //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("././example.in")));

    String[] parts = br.readLine().split("(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])");
    /*for(int i=0; i<parts.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.print(parts[i]);
        System.out.print("\n");

    }*/

    int cCount = 0;
    int hCount = 0;
    int nCount = 0;
    int oCount = 0;

    ArrayList<String> listOfEdges = new ArrayList<String>();


    for(int i=0; i<parts.length;i++)
    {
        if(parts[i].equals("C"))
        {
            cCount = Integer.parseInt(parts[i+1]);
        }
        if(parts[i].equals("H"))
        {
            hCount = Integer.parseInt(parts[i+1]);
        }
        if(parts[i].equals("N"))
        {
            nCount = Integer.parseInt(parts[i+1]);
        }
        if(parts[i].equals("O"))
        {
            oCount = Integer.parseInt(parts[i+1]);
        }
        //System.out.print(parts[i]);

    }
    int numberOfEdges = (4*cCount + hCount + 3*nCount + 2*oCount)/2-hCount;
    int r = numberOfEdges;
    int nodeNum = cCount + nCount + oCount;


     for(int i=1;i<=(cCount+nCount+oCount-1);i++)
     {
         for(int j=i+1;j<=cCount+nCount+oCount;j++)
         {
             listOfEdges.add(Integer.toString(i) + " " + Integer.toString(j));
             listOfEdges.add(Integer.toString(i) + " " + Integer.toString(j));
             if(j<=cCount+nCount)
             {
             listOfEdges.add(Integer.toString(i) + " " + Integer.toString(j));
             }
         }

     }
    /*listOfEdges.add("1 2");
    listOfEdges.add("1 2");
    listOfEdges.add("1 3");
    listOfEdges.add("2 3");
    listOfEdges.add("2 4");*/

    listOfEdges.trimToSize();
    ArrayList<String> returnArray = new ArrayList<String>(r);
    for(int i=0; i<r ;i++)
    {
        returnArray.add(null);
    }
    generateCombinations(listOfEdges, returnArray, 0, listOfEdges.size()-1, 0, r, nodeNum,cCount,nCount,oCount);




















    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.print("cCount: ");
    System.out.print(cCount);
    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.print("hCount: ");
    System.out.print(hCount);
    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.print("nCount: ");
    System.out.print(nCount);
    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.print("oCount: ");
    System.out.print(oCount);
    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.print(numberOfEdges);
    System.out.print("\n");
}

}
```

It just skips over it in debug mode, no errors or anything. Any help or hints is much appreciated.

Comment: It's empty so there's nothing to loop over.

Comment: You should be capable enough to keep removing parts of code irrelevant to your problem until you come up with a minimal piece which still reproduces the error. At that point the problem will probably have solved itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enhanced for-loop iterates over all elements of the the given [iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html), since your `twoArray` is empty there's nothing to iterate.

Comment: Of course, this is it. I'm sorry, been coding for two days straight and my brain isn't working properly anymore.